# Queue Kendall Notation

Tags: queueing-theory

How to understand that queue model in Kendall notation?

M/G/S/Q

I don't understand letter G.

Can someone give good resource or simple explanation what G stands for?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: $G$ stands for General. It is where the service behavior is not specified.